# Pickle.dump to variable

Tags: python, pickle

I'm new in python and i wanted to know if there is a solution for this problem:

I know that this may sound strange but i want to save the pickle.dump data into a variable.
I begin to think that may i could bypass it by making a fake class to instead of writing in a file, writing in a variable:

```
class PickleDatatoVar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
    def write(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def get(self):
        return self.data
```

and then:

```
pick = PickleDatatoVar()
pickle.dump(Int, pick)
var = pick.get()
```

Nothing is presented as error, but the output is just a '.'

So is there a solution to instead of saving that in a file saving into a variable?

Comment: What is the point of dumping it to a variable ? Just use that variable directly.

Comment: because i wanted to send that through a socket

Comment: Are you looking for `pickle.dumps` (Return the pickled representation of the object as a string, instead of writing it to a file.)? https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps

Comment: What Mark said, and also note that `PickleDatatoVar` exists in the stdlib, it's called `cStringIO.StringIO`. Your implementation fails because it doesn't handle multiple writes into the same `PickleDatatoVar` - it only retains the last write, which in case of pickle happens to be the terminating `.`.

Comment: @downvoter: the OP is obviously a newbie, but it is clear that he tried to solve the problem himself, and carefully presented the effort. Despite missing `pickle.dumps`, research effort is undeniable.

Answer (score 17):

You are looking for an in-memory file object; in Python 2 that's [`cStringIO.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), for Python 3 [`io.BytesIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO); these act just like file objects and you can have `pickle.dump()` write to these.

However, the easier path would be to use [`pickle.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) to dump straight to a string object instead.

*Under the hood*, what `pickle.dumps()` does for you is create an in-memory file object, write the pickle data to it and retrieve the string result for you; see the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd8b5b5b6356/Lib/pickle.py#l1536):

```
def _dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    _Pickler(f, protocol, fix_imports=fix_imports).dump(obj)
    res = f.getvalue()
    assert isinstance(res, bytes_types)
    return res
```

but this way you don't have to do that extra work yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the code snippets using [pickle.dump()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) in case you need:

Dumping from pickle_obj to bytes/string variable

```
bytes_output = BytesIO()
pickle.dump(pickle_obj, model_bytes)
bytes_output_base64 = base64.b64encode(model_bytes.getvalue()).decode() # convert the bytes to base64 string
bytes_output.close()
```

Loading from a base64 string in pickle_data to pickle_obj

```
pickle_bytes = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(pickle_data))
pickle_obj = pickle.loads(pickle_bytes.read())
pickle_bytes.close()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick and clean explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890916/python3-unpickle-a-string-representation-of-bytes-object) on stackoverlfow by Farhan K:

```
import pickle

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
string_of_bytes_obj = str(pickle.dumps(mydict), encoding="latin1")

unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(bytes(string_of_bytes_obj, "latin1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its late but I came across this same issue and here's a solution that I came up with. And I apologize for my bad English

add this class to your code

```
class DataPacket:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, string):
        self._string = string

    @property
    def string(self):
        return self._string
```

and where u dump your pickled result use this

```
    PickeledString = DataPacket()
    pickle.dump(dataJSON, PickeledString)
```

to read it use this

```
PickeledString.string
```