# Python3 unpickle a string representation of bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Is there a good way to load a bytes object that is represented as a string, so it can be unpickled?

### Basic Example

Here is a dumb example:

```
import pickle

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
string_of_bytes_obj = str(pickle.dumps(mydict)) # Deliberate string representation for this quick example.

unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(string_of_bytes_obj) # ERROR!  Loads takes bytes-like object and not string.
```

### Attempt at a Solution

One solution is of course to `eval` the string:

```
unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(eval(string_of_bytes_obj))
```

But, seems wrong to `eval`, especially when the strings might be coming over a network or from a file.

...

Any suggestions for a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it is much better just not to convert bytes to str. Is there any way to avoid that conversion?

Comment: @soon I'm just processing a file from someone else... would definitely be better to change their file to use binary data... but right now, I can't avoid the string conversion.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use pickle with network data btw: http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2007/11/09/one-cookie-please/

Comment: Do you know what the encoding of the file is? If you do then you just have to `str.encode` the string to unpickle. If you don't you need to guess the encoding first.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin not sure I understand.  What would be the encoding of the string?  I know the file is utf-8, but I think all that gives me is a way to get the string representation in a known encoding, and I would still need to eval... or do you mean something like the answer provided by @Farhan.K?

Comment: Yes I meant something along the line of @Farhan.K's answer, but since you get the string from a given file you have to know which encoding was used to produce it. If you know it, you can reverse the operation to get the bytes object and unpickle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a safety concern you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval(string_of_bytes_obj))
{'b': 2222, 'a': 1111}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Great answer.  Safer evaluation, just needs some extra error handling.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `encoding="latin1"` as an argument to `str` and then use `bytes` to convert back:

```
import pickle

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
string_of_bytes_obj = str(pickle.dumps(mydict), encoding="latin1")

unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(bytes(string_of_bytes_obj, "latin1"))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(unpickled_dict)
{'a': 1111, 'b': 2222}
```

Comment: Why does this work?! I just spent 2 hours trying to figure this out. No answers anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to have it as a str? If you're just writing it to file, you can 'wb' instead of 'w'. (https://pythontips.com/2013/08/02/what-is-pickle-in-python/)

```
import pickle

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
dumped = pickle.dumps(mydict)
string_of_bytes_obj = str(dumped) # Deliberate string representation for this quick example. 

unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(dumped)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not my file, I'm just processing what I'm given!

Answer (score 0):

First of all i wouldn't use pickles to serialize data. instead use Json.

my solution with pickles

```
import pickle

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
string_of_bytes_obj = pickle.dumps(mydict) # Deliberate string representation for this quick example.
print(string_of_bytes_obj)
unpickled_dict = pickle.loads(string_of_bytes_obj)
print(unpickled_dict)
```

BUT with json

```
import json

mydict = { 'a': 1111, 'b': 2222 }
string_of_bytes_obj = json.dumps(mydict) 
print(string_of_bytes_obj)
unpickled_dict = json.loads(string_of_bytes_obj)
print(unpickled_dict)
```

I highly recommend you to use json to serialize your data