# Pickle/Unpickle more complicated objects

Tags: django, persistence, pickle, python-3.7

I'm having a more complicated object which also contains some inheritances and so on. I'd like to be able to pickle/unpickle it and save it as file in my git. But it only works while it's still in the memory. When I'm reading it as a file I can't convert it back properly.

As long as I'm just using it within my python (Django) application it's fine:

```
myPickle=pickle.dumps(reallyComplicatedObject, 0).decode()
...
myObject = pickle.loads(myPickle.encode())
```

Now I'm saving it for further usage (I'm having to pretend it's a file as Django won't allow me to save a string as a file):

```
fs = FileSystemStorage()

notAFile = io.StringIO(pickle.dumps(reallyComplicatedObject, 0).decode())
filename = fs.save(filename, notAFile)
return fs.url(filename)
```

This did as it was supposed to. I'm having a file that looks more or less binary to me
Now the unpickle:

```
storage_class = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)
complicatedPickle = None

with storage_class().open('TestFiles/Pickles/thatOneObject') as picklereads:
    complicatedPickle = picklereads.read()
pick = pickle.loads(complicatedPickle)
```

When I output `complicatedPickle` I'm getting a long string that does look binary to me. Here I wonder already as I expected a String - but it is:

```
(Pdb) type(complicatedPickle)
<class 'bytes'>
```

`pick` is a String and encoding it just makes it binary again:

```
(Pdb) type(pick)
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) type(pick.encode())
<class 'bytes'>
```

I've tried to use `ast` like in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52891113/2516892

```
nopick = pickle.loads(ast.literal_eval(complicatedPickle))
```

But something is going wrong as this just outputs the object. I'm not having a `nopick` variable afterwards.

The next solution on the same page is not helpful either:

```
(Pdb) unpick=pickle.loads(bytes(complicatedPickle))
(Pdb) type(unpick)
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) unpick=pickle.loads(bytes(complicatedPickle, "latin1"))
*** TypeError: encoding without a string argument
(Pdb) unpick=pickle.load(bytes(complicatedPickle, "latin1"))
*** TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

I'm stuck now. Is there an error in my conversion already? Or how am I supposed to objectify it again? Or could the problem be Django-Related as I'm not using the regular `open`, but `storage_class`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems in here:

1. `FileSystemStorage` can't write binary files and `StringIO` can't pretend the String is binary (or maybe can, but it's not really trivial)
2. Reading a non-binary saved file and pretend it's actually binary is not working.

I needed to ditch my save-function to a non-Django Style:

```
import os
    sfilename = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,
                             "TestFiles/Pickles/"+filename)

    with open(sfilename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(obj, 0)) #also not decoding it any more

    return sfilename
```

The retrieving is more easy:

```
with storage_class().open('TestFiles/Pickles/'+filename, mode='rb') as pickle:
            complicatedObject = pickle.load(pickle)
```

And that's actually it