# How do I fix EOFError when unpickling from a BytesIO object?

Tags: python, pickle

Is this possible to pickle and **unpickle** data **without** creating a file for it? In the question that was suggested as duplicate I don't see how to unpickle this.

> [Pickle.dump to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856656/pickle-dump-to-variable)

I want to do this remotely so I can't create new files on the fly.
All examples with pickling and unpickling show use of pickle.dump, and pickle.load.
I read the docs, and the file argument can be a BytesIO object but when I try to use load() function, I get.

> EOFError: Ran out of input

Can somebody give me some examples of how to do this?
What I currently have is:

```
a = A("some_random_string")
bio = BytesIO(b"some_bytes_data")
d = pickle.dump(a, bio)
f = pickle.Unpickler(bio).load()
```

The load gives me the above error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _why_? If you want to serialize your data, just use JSON?

Comment: There's `pickle.dumps` and `pickle.loads`, but using a `BytesIO` object should work as well. Can we have a [mcve]?

Comment: @Aran-fey presumably you're seeing a use-case that I don't?

Comment: @roganjosh Well, yeah, there are some things that aren't json serializable.

Comment: Actually, forget the MCVE: It looks like you simply forgot to call `bio.seek(0)` before unpickling.

Comment: @Aran-fey but wont`pickle` make the whole thing more difficult? Like, put yourself in a right `pickle` (I'll see myself out)

Comment: @roganjosh Ease of use is actually one of pickle's very few advantages - it can serialize most things out of the box, at the cost of risking arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @Aran-fey but DSM has hinted to me in the past that it fixes you to particular python versions. I didn't look into that so much but it definitely comes with restrictions.

Comment: @roganjosh It's true that pickle can cause version incompatibilities, but there are still valid use cases for it. Let's not turn this question into a discussion about whether pickle is better or worse than other serialization formats.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, could you re-open this topic, since I edited it. There is no answer in the "duplicate" of how to unpickle such a data. I still get the EOFError.

Comment: Did you try `bio.seek(0)`? Also, why the heck are you initializing your `BytesIO` object with data inside it? Also, why are you using `BytesIO` instead of `pickle.dumps`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it after all. Using dumps instead of dump made it possible for me.
An example of how it works in my case now:

```
from io import BytesIO
import pickle
a = b"asdf"
f = pickle.dumps(a)
file = BytesIO(f)
unpickled = pickle.load(file) # It is equal to initial value.
```

Maybe it helps someone else too.